# mariabackup fails with Error: cannot mkdir 2: /data/backups/mariadb/

Tags: backup, mariadb, rocky-linux

Trying to use mariabackup to take backup of all our databases. First created backup directory as

```
mkdir -p /mnt/data/backup/mariadb
chown -R mysql:mysql /mnt/data/backup/mariadb
```

And proceed to do backup

```
# mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/mnt/data/backups/mariadb/ --user=root --password=xxxxxxxx
[00] 2022-02-06 11:28:46 Connecting to MySQL server host: localhost, user: root, password: set, port: not set, socket: /mnt/data/mysql/mysql.sock
[00] 2022-02-06 11:28:46 Using server version 10.3.28-MariaDB
mariabackup based on MariaDB server 10.3.28-MariaDB Linux (x86_64)
[00] 2022-02-06 11:28:46 uses posix_fadvise().
[00] 2022-02-06 11:28:46 cd to /mnt/data/mysql/
[00] 2022-02-06 11:28:46 open files limit requested 0, set to 1024
[00] 2022-02-06 11:28:46 mariabackup: using the following InnoDB configuration:
[00] 2022-02-06 11:28:46 innodb_data_home_dir = 
[00] 2022-02-06 11:28:46 innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
[00] 2022-02-06 11:28:46 innodb_log_group_home_dir = ./
[00] 2022-02-06 11:28:46 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-02-06 11:28:46 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
[00] 2022-02-06 11:28:46 Error: cannot mkdir 2: /mnt/data/backups/mariadb/
```

tried goggling and various options it did not worked so finally tried without --target-directory option and did backup again and it worked successfully and got this

```
# ls -ld /mnt/data/backup
drwxr-xr-x 3 mysql mysql 21 Feb  6 11:41 /mnt/data/backup

# pwd
/mnt/data/mysql

# ll
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 mysql mysql   21 Feb  6 11:41 backup
drwxr-xr-x 27 mysql mysql 4096 Feb  4 19:07 mysql
drwx------ 27 root  root  4096 Feb  6 11:22 xtrabackup_backupfiles
```

What did I do wrong or how do I run this with ----target-directory

Comment: Please provide `ls -ld /mnt/data/backups/`

Comment: Updated details in the above question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo in your commands.
The commands

```
mkdir -p /mnt/data/backup/mariadb
chown -R mysql:mysql /mnt/data/backup/mariadb
```

created the directory /mnt/data/backup/mariadb but the command

```
mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/mnt/data/backups/mariadb/ ...
```

asked `mariabackup` to write to /mnt/data/backup**s**/mariadb.
The parent directory /mnt/data/backup**s** of that directory probably does not exist.
Since `mariabackup` as per its manpage only creates the target directory itself if necessary, but not the path leading to it, it errored out.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @tilman schmidt @Rick James for your guidance. I corrected my typos, path and also deleted the mariadb folder i.e /mnt/data/backup/**mariadb**

And ran the command again and it worked successfully.

```
mariabackup --backup --target-dir=/mnt/data/backup/mariadb/ --user=root --password=xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Please accept the answer that solved your issue. Posting it again is neither necessary nor helpful to others.